# How can i combine rows range into json format?

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet like this

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/346I8.jpg]

The number of columns and rows may be different (not static). I want my google script to look for last row and column, then run a for loop and combine data of each row into this json format like this.

```
[["1","Lee","Blue","Active"],["2","Mike","Green","Disabled"],["3","Chan","Yellow","Active"]]
```

I learned about the JSON.stringify() function that helps and I am able to combine data or each row into json format BUT i want each row data separated by a comma (,), not sure how to add that in the logic since I DO NOT want comma to be added after LAST row.

I have tried creating this code and need help with the logic to dynamically run the loop based on number of columns and rows instead of hard-coding any range and add comma.

```
var mysheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('mysheet');

function combine_val() {

GetRowsCount();
var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
var numRows = LastAudienceRow; // Number of rows to process

for (var i = 0; i < numRows; ++i) {
var dataRange = mysheet.getRange(startRow, 1, 1, 4);
var data = dataRange.getValues();
startRow = startRow+1;
var data2= JSON.stringify(data);
}

SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(data2); 

}



function GetRowsCount() {
LastAudienceRow = mysheet.getLastRow() - 1;
return LastAudienceRow;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've rather over complicated the whole situation, as much of this is done automatically. This script is also not very efficient and when you add more runs, will take too long to execute, eventually hitting the App script limit for maximum execution time.

Here you are trying to get the data from each row individually, and add it to an array. This is very inefficient, and it's much better/faster to just specify the range of data you want. Happily, this also formats it's pretty much as you like.

Here's a sample script:

```
var mysheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('mysheet');

function combine_val() {
var startRow = 1; // First row of data to process.
var startColumn = 1; //First Column to process, in case that changes.

var numRows = mysheet.getLastRow(); // Number of rows to process
var numCols = mysheet.getLastColumn(); //Also the number of columns to process, again in case that changes.
var dataRange = mysheet.getRange(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numCols);//Get the full range of data in the sheet dynamically. 
var data = JSON.stringify(dataRange.getValues());//Get the value of the range, AND convert it to a JSON string in one line.

Logger.log(data); //Use the in built logger to read the values that are returned. You can read this by pressing 'ctrl+enter'. 
}
```

I've also added in some sample dynamic improvements which will mean you are hard coding less of your values into your scripts, preventing it from breaking if the data changes.

Additionally, I have added in a sample of how to read the data via the inbuilt logging tool, rather then via a cumbersome pop up after every run.

Comment: Thank you so much @HDCerberus you are right, I was over complicating the code. Thanks for your help. One question. the reason i am changing the values to JSON format is because i am passing "data" variable to API that only accept JSON format. I just learned that API only accept max of 200 rows. I have posted a new question here: [New Question Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57822236/how-can-i-create-batch-in-javascript-loop-to-select-x-rows-then-next-x-rows-unti)

Answer (score 1):

JSON.stringify already returns row data separated by commas.

```js
var arr = [["1","Lee","Blue","Active"],["2","Mike","Green","Disabled"],["3","Chan","Yellow","Active"]];
console.info(JSON.stringify(arr))
```

The above example prints the following string to the console

```
[["1","Lee","Blue","Active"],["2","Mike","Green","Disabled"],["3","Chan","Yellow","Active"]]
```

The following example prints each row values separated by comma.

```js
var arr = [["1","Lee","Blue","Active"],["2","Mike","Green","Disabled"],["3","Chan","Yellow","Active"]];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  console.info(JSON.stringify(arr[i]).replace(/[\[\]]/g,''));
}
```

To use it on as a Google Sheets / Apps Script instead of assigning a literal to `arr` use `getValues()` . You could replace console.info by `SpreadsheetApp.getUi.alert(message)` too.

Comment: Thank you @Ruben yes i have now learned that JSON.stringify does everything for me and i do not have to go row by row.