# how can I create batch in javascript loop to select x Rows then next x Rows until all rows are done?

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I have a google sheet with some data and I am trying to combine all cell data in a JSON variable so I can pass it on to API to do something.

I have this javascript function that takes all data and combine everything in JSON variable like this:

```
function combine_val() {
var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process. Starting with 2 to ignore headers
var startColumn = 1; //First Column to process, in case that changes.

var numRows = mysheet.getLastRow(); // Number of rows to process
var numCols = mysheet.getLastColumn(); //Also the number of columns to process, again in case that changes.
var dataRange = mysheet.getRange(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numCols);//Get the full range of data in the sheet dynamically. 
var data = JSON.stringify(dataRange.getValues());//Get the value of the range, AND convert it to a JSON string in one line.

// DO something HERE with "data" to push the JSON string in a controlled batch to API

SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(data);  
}
```

The API where I am passing this data takes JSON with 200 rows only. So I need help in creating a batch of 200.

This is what I have done so far and need help.

```
var mybatch = 200;

function combine_val_increment() {
var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process. Starting with 2 to ignore headers
var startColumn = 1; //First Column to process, in case that changes.

var numRows = mysheet.getLastRow(); // Number of rows to process
var numCols = mysheet.getLastColumn(); //Also the number of columns to process, again in case that changes.

for (var i = 0; i < numRows/mybatch; ++i) {

var dataRange = mysheet.getRange(startRow, startColumn, startRow+mybatch, numCols);//Get the full range of data in the sheet dynamically. 
var data = JSON.stringify(dataRange.getValues());//Get the value of the range, AND convert it to a JSON string in one line.

// DO something HERE with "data" to push the JSON string in a controlled batch to API

SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(data); 
 startRow = startRow + mybatch;

}


}
```

**Approach# 2 based on suggestions / comments**

```
function rowsForAPI2(){
  var batchsize = 2;
  //var batchsize = 200;

  //var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet5'); //SHEET NAME
 // var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues(); // 2D array with all of the data in the sheet.


var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process. Skip 1st row of column headers for this test.
var startColumn = 1; //First Column to process, in case that changes.
var numRows = ss.getLastRow(); // Number of rows to process
//var numCols = mysheet.getLastColumn(); //Also the number of columns to process, again in case that changes.
var numCols = 4; //Hardcode for this test
var dataRange = ss.getRange(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numCols);//Get the full range of data in the sheet dynamically. 
var data = dataRange.getValues();//Get the value of the range, AND convert it to a JSON string in one line.  



  var rowCount = ss.getLastRow() - 1; // To know how many rows have data (-1 will ignore the column header)
  var obj = [];
  var temp = 0;
  var results = [];

  Logger.log(rowCount/batchsize)
  for (var i = 0; i < (rowCount/batchsize); i++){  
    for (var j  = temp; j < batchsize*(i+1); j++){
      obj.push(data[j]); // Push row into object.
      temp = j;
      if (temp == rowCount-1) // Got to the end of the data.
        break;
    }
    temp++;
    results.push(JSON.stringify(obj)); // Adds the JSON object to an array
    obj = []; // Clear the array of the 200 rows stored
  }
  return results;
}

function doSomething(){
  var objects = rowsForAPI2();
  var curr;
  for ( var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++){
    curr = objects[i];
    // Do the API thing with curr...

    Logger.log(curr);
  }
}
```

**New requirement for approach 3 -**

In this new use-case, instead of passing data in JSON.stringify array of 200 rows batch. I have an API endpoint that takes rows in this format:

```
{
  "recipient": {
    "emailAddress": "email_1@domain.com",
    "listName": {
      "path": "testfolder"         
    }
  }

},
{
  "recipient": {
    "emailAddress": "email_2@domain.com",
    "listName": {
       "path": "testfolder" 
    }
  }

},
{
  "recipient": {
    "emailAddress": "email_3@domain.com",
    "listName": {
       "path": "testfolder" 
    }
  }

}
```

How can I use same solution discussed below with batching technique but for building the above^ formatted records where email list is coming from values in rows in google sheet? Any help?

Comment: You should use `mysheet.getDataRange().getValues()` ([Documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)), it will give you a 2D array of the entire data range, then you can iterate through it more comfortably, stopping every 200 rows. Aside from that, what is the issue you're having, are you getting errors?

Comment: My above approach is not correct? I am having trouble with the loop logic and not sure how to increment last row which will be different for each batch. I am getting alert with all data then batch data. I would appreciate any kind of help with the loop logic to make this a 200 per batch approach.

Comment: it's not incorrect, but using `getDataRange()` would be more comfortable, and it will get everything so you don't need to worry about whether it gets the last row. As for the loop, you can add an internal loop that goes through 200 rows, parses them into the JSON how you're doing and then just append everything together.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could please help me with the code (with the new approach that you are proposing). It will help me in understanding the concept.

Comment: Sure, I'll give it a go and post an answer when possible.

Comment: Thank you @AMolina looking forward to your sample code

Comment: Hi @AMolina I really appreciate your help and just wanted to follow up if you got a chance test this use-case? Thank you so much once again.

Comment: Hi! Sorry, the weekend was cramped, but I am taking a look into it today, I will post as soon as possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function rowsForAPI(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues(); // 2D array with all of the data in the sheet.
  var rowCount = ss.getLastRow(); // To know how many rows have data
  var obj = []; // Array where the row objects will be stored 
  var temp = 0; // A counter of how many rows have been processed. 
  var results = []; // Array where the resulting JSON objects will be stored and returned.

  Logger.log(rowCount/200)
  for (var i = 0; i < (rowCount/200); i++){  
    for (var j  = temp; j < 200*(i+1); j++){
      obj.push(data[j]); // Push row into object.
      temp = j;
      if (temp == rowCount-1) // Got to the end of the data (if there are less than 200 rows in this batch).
        break;
    }
    temp++; // Update row count.
    results.push(JSON.stringify(obj)); // Adds the JSON object to an array
    obj = []; // Clear the array of the 200 rows stored before the next loop starts.
  }
  return results;
}

function doSomething(){
  var objects = rowsForAPI();
  var curr;
  for ( var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++){ // Go through each batch
    curr = objects[i]; // Current batch.
    // Do the API thing with curr...
  }
}
```

This method will return an array of JSON objects that holds batches of 200 rows from the Sheet, it will also stop if it reaches the end of the data in the sheet.

Comment: Hi @Amolina first of all thank you so much for your help and providing the code example. I used your approach, added some additional code to match my original code so that i can control range of data for my test and defined a variable for batchsize for a test (trying to test the logic with batchsize = 1). I have updated my code above ^ based on your suggestion. If you see my original code (my previous approach), I have added comments to //DO something with the JSON string. Where in your code I need to do that? I am trying to understand the approach here.

Comment: Also - In your current approach, if data is not 200 then it won't matter, the code will know automatically the number of rows to process which is less than 200?

Comment: You don't have to do the things with the JSON necessarily inside the code I posted. You said you need the objects for the API you're using, correct? I updated my code to show how you would use the object. Where the comment is at the bottom you would use your API (`apiMethod(curr)`, for example). As for the less than 200, yes, the code will only get the rows with data, you'll be fine whether you have 50 rows or 500

Comment: WOW @Amolina this worked!! Thank you so much. Based on what I learned from your approach, I can use this technique in so many places now. I did some minors updates again for just my testing to control the range of rows and columns and removing column headers by subtracting -1 from rowCount. I am getting desired result now. Could you please review my updated code posted above ^ and let me know if you see any issues. Thank you so much for guiding me here. Learned a new approach today :)

Comment: All looks good, I would still suggest you use `ss.getDataRange().getValues();` just to make it easier to work with, you could achieve the same (ignoring the headers) by initializing `temp` to 1 instead of 0, but that's completely up to you.  Aside from that it all looks good, glad to hear it's working.

Comment: Good to know..Thank you so much...Do you mind explaining variables used in this approach like temp and other ones? What they are doing? Just so I have a crystal clear understanding of this approach.

Comment: Thank you @AMolina for adding comments in the code. Very helpful! :)

Comment: No problem, happy to help!!

Comment: Hi @AMolina i have a new use-case where I am trying to apply your solution / approach that we discussed before. I have explained the new use-case above in my question as approach 3. Could you please help me with the code where i can create a batch of records similar to the sample that I have posted (instead of JSON.stringify array).

Comment: Hi @kuml you should open a new question for this type of request, updating older questions is not good in Stack Overflow. Opening a new one will be even better for you because it'll be more visible.

Comment: Thanks @AMolina I was able to modify your solution and make it work in my new use-case. If I have any additional question, I will connect with you and post a new question. Thanks